# Simulate button press effect

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro assigned to a rectangle shape that goes to the next sheet in my workbook.

I'm trying to add a press down and up effect to this rectangle.

When I use this code, the rectangle is only pressed down then then the next sheet is activated, and if I returned back to the previous sheet, the rectangle is released.

Wht I need is that the rectangle is pressed down and then released before going to the next sheet.

```
Dim MyButton As Shape
Dim oHeight, oWidth, cHeight, cWidth As Double
Dim oTop, oLeft As Long

Public Sub PressButton()
    Set MyButton = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    With MyButton
        'Record original button properties.
        oHeight = .Height
        oWidth = .Width
        oTop = .Top
        oLeft = .Left
        'Button Down (Simulate button click).
        .ScaleHeight 0.9, msoFalse
        .ScaleWidth 0.9, msoFalse
        cHeight = .Height
        cWidth = .Width
        .Top = oTop + ((oHeight - cHeight) / 2)
        .Left = oLeft + ((oWidth - cWidth) / 2)
    End With

    'Set MyButton variable to Nothing to free memory.
    Set MyButton = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub ReleaseButton()
    Set MyButton = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    With MyButton
        'Button Up (Set back to original button properties).
        .Height = oHeight
        .Width = oWidth
        .Top = oTop
        .Left = oLeft
    End With

    'Set MyButton variable to Nothing to free memory.
    Set MyButton = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub NextPage()
    PressButton
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
    ReleaseButton

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Do While Not ws.Next.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Set ws = ws.Next
    Loop

    With ws.Next
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Expanded answer below: this question has recently become very interesting indeed. The answer doesn't **quite** give an instant 'press button' animation (see the remark after the very last block of code)  but it's close enough.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using a 'Command Button': shapes and rectangle objects don't really support the event-driven 'On Click' functionality you need here: calling an associated macro is pretty much all that they do.

However, you may well be stuck with that shape as your interface (support for ActiveX command buttons is very poor in 64-bit environments), so here goes...

#### Background: how to make a button look like a button:

Most shapes have a 'Shadow' property, and an outside shadow cast by a light source from a 45-degree angle (from the top-left corner) gives a 'raised' effect. Conversely, an inside shadow cast from the opposite angle (from a light source off the bottom-right corner) gives a 'sunken' effect.

In practice, an inside shadow for both is good enough: just change the angle.

In VBA, the 'angle' of the light source for your shape's shadow is given as X and Y offsets, and 45 degrees corresponds to 1.14142:

`Dim oShape As Excel.Shape
Dim oShadow As Excel.ShadowFormat

    Set oShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(i)
    Set oShadow = oShape.Shadow

   ' Shadow cast by light from above-right at 45 degrees for a 'raised' effect:
    oShadow.OffsetX = Sqr(2)
    oShadow.OffsetY = Sqr(2)

   ' Shadow cast by light from above-right at minus 45 degrees for a 'sunken' effect:
    oShadow.OffsetX = -Sqr(2)
    oShadow.OffsetY = -Sqr(2)`


...And that's the code for your click 'up' and click 'down' button state.

I Strongly recommend that you use the built-in dialogs to set the shape's fill colour and the shadow's size, transparency and blur. For your reference, the settings I use for a smart 'semi-flat' light grey button are listed below - but I do not recommend that you set them in VBA code, as these formats will not be applied in the order you expect, and the button will not look like the 'clean' shape you can build using the UI dialogs:
    `' Light-grey button with a slightly darker 'softened' border
    oShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = &HD8D8D8
    oShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = &HC0C0C0
    oShape.Line.Weight = 2
    oShape.Line.Transparency = 0.75

   ' Use the shape's shadow to give a 'raised button' effect:
    oShadow.Style = msoShadowStyleInnerShadow
    oShadow.Visible = True
    oShadow.Blur = 2
    oShadow.Size = 100
    oShadow.Transparency = 0.5

   ' Shadow cast by light from above-right at 45 degrees for a 'raised' effect:
    oShadow.OffsetX = Sqr(2)
    oShadow.OffsetY = Sqr(2)`


You can also use the 3-D effects dialog, but this works by a 'chisel' effect for most shapes (including your rectangle): I haven't found any predefined 'raised' or 'sunken' three-D styles for shapes.

#### Major Edit:

Guess who's looking at the job of replacing **all** the Active-X control buttons on all the tactical spreadsheet tools before the 64-Bit Office rollout renders  them inoperable?

So your question just became very, very interesting indeed. Here's what I'm doing about that:

### Generic 'Button Click' code for using Excel 'Shape' objects to call a VBA Macro instead of ActiveX controls.

This is what I'm using instead of ActiveX buttons: text labels, rectangles and images, placed into the worksheet using the 'Insert' menu on the Ribbon.

These objects are all Excel 'Shapes', they can all be associated with a named macro, and they have a common 'shadow' effect that serves as a 'raised button' 3D effect.

The example below is a function call from an image (it's a 32*32 icon for a database, with a question mark) embedded as a shape on a worksheet. I gave this ersatz control button a meaningful name, and I named the macro `[Name]_Click()`, because I'm replacing the existing 'Click' event procedures.

So this macro is a public subroutine on a worksheet identified with a **code** name,  - users can 'rename' the sheet, changing the user-readable label, but they won't rename the underlying VBA class module - and it's visible as `MySheetCodeName.img_TestDefaultDSN_Click()` in the 'assign macro' list when you right-click the shape.

..That's why it's Public (not Private, as the automatically-created event procedure stubs for ActiveX controls will be): private subs aren't visible in the 'Assign Macro' list.

`Public Sub img_TestDefaultDSN_Click()

ClickDown Me.Shapes("img_TestDefaultDB")
ShowDBStatus "EOD_Reports_DSN"
ClickUp Me.Shapes("img_TestDefaultDB")

End Sub`

This calls a pair of generic 'Click Down' and 'Click Up' subroutines, in a regular code module:

`Public Function ClickDown(objShape As Excel.Shape)
On Error Resume Next

'Recast the button shadow from bottom-right to top-left:
With objShape.Shadow
   .Visible = msoFalse
    .OffsetX = -1.2
    .OffsetY = -1.2
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Blur = 1
    .Size = 99
    .Transparency = 0.75
    .Style = msoShadowStyleInnerShadow
    .Obscured = msoFalse
End With

'Darken the button face slightly:
If objShape.Type = msoPicture Then
    With objShape.PictureFormat
        .Brightness = .Brightness - 0.01
    End With
Else
    With objShape.Fill
       .Visible = msoTrue
       .ForeColor.Brightness = .ForeColor.Brightness - 0.01
    End With
End If

End Function


Public Function ClickUp(objShape As Excel.Shape)
On Error Resume Next

'Restore the button face to it's default brightness:
With objShape.Shadow
    .Visible = msoFalse
    .OffsetX = 1.2
    .OffsetY = 1.2
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Blur = 1
    .Size = 99
    .Transparency = 0.75
    .Style = msoShadowStyleInnerShadow
    .Obscured = msoFalse
End With

'Restore the button shadow to bottom-right:
If objShape.Type = msoPicture Then
    With objShape.PictureFormat
        .Brightness = .Brightness + 0.01
    End With
Else
    With objShape.Fill
       .Visible = msoTrue
       .ForeColor.Brightness = .ForeColor.Brightness + 0.01
    End With
End If

End Function`


You may well have your own preferences for the appearance of a 'control button', but this works for me.

Note that the  'Click Down' effect is never seen if 'Click Up' follows immediately: nor even if a 'Sleep' or an 'Application Wait' statement separates them - you'll only see it if there's real code with a user-detectable elapsed time or a modal dialog.

Comment: I'm finding issue with the screen not updating between `ClickDown` and `ClickUp`. I have a call to `ClickDown` follow by a `MsgBox` then `ClickUp`. No visible changes occur. If I only do the `ClickDown` and `MsgBox`, no updates occur until after the `MsgBox` is closed. The effects work independently, but not combined. So I'm sure I'm missing something horribly obvious. Hints?

Comment: Above issue resolved by turning off screen updating before the call to `ClickDown` and turning it back on at the end of `ClickDown`. A `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of `ClickDown` failed. I found both the off then the on were required.

Comment: Wouldn't using a simple Form Control button work just as well, without all of this overhead?

Comment: Yes @Jon - a form button would work just as well... On a 32-bit installation of MS-Office.  The problem is an implacably hostile admin team rolling out 64-bit office and deactivating all the Active-X controls, and  the only UI controls we can use in this impoverished environment are the old 'macro button' objects - is that what you mean by 'Form Control' ? They are far, far less functional than an ActiveX control, and the overhead I've posted here is the overspill from other work intended to implement events and the double-click / right-click interfaces we're losing.

Comment: They're a bit extreme to disable the ActiveX controls, but most veteran Excel developers avoid them. They're flaky, and don't run on Macs. (The 32- vs 64-bit thing is a red herring, though; I don't think this has any effect.) All you're doing though is using a shape instead of a button. At least the button has built-in behavior you're trying to coax out of the shape. The benefit of the shape is more flexibility when formatting. But neither shape nor form button have any events, unlike the ActiveX controls, and the shadow to simulate mouse down and up are about all you can do with the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use Private subs. You only need to change the way you call the subroutines. To call private sub, even located in another code module, you have to use:

```
Application.Run "[ModuleName.]MacroName"[, arg1] [,arg2...],
```

Everything is in details explained here:

https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/3-ways-to-call-a-private-sub-from-another-module/